# ArcCatalog open sde geodb fails: "possibly sdehome/temp is full"

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-10.4, arccatalog

I'm trying to open a connection to an sde geodatabase with ArcCatalog 10.4.1 that was previously working. But now I get the error:

`"possibly $SDEHOME/temp is full"`

and ArcCatalog crashes.

Does anyone have any idea on what the issue could be?

Comment: What are you doing when you get the error? I quick google search shows some threads on [geonet](https://community-qa.esri.com/thread/50194), [2](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/59110) have you tried anything discussed there? Knowing this may help narrow down answers.

Comment: I was trying to open the geodb by double clicking on the .sde connection. Yes, I've seen the threads you suggest, unfortunately none of the things discussed there helped.

Comment: Did anything change on your system/with the geodatabase from before when it worked to now when it doesn't?

Comment: No, nothing. Another strange thing is that the same sde connection works if used from another machine.

Comment: Did you get this fixed? I have the same issue; however, it works with one user account and not another on the same machine.